# How put a photo on xamarin in the selected location?

Tags: c#, xamarin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ww2W.png)

I decided to add the logo to the specified location, but I do not know how this can be done

Comment: use an `Image` control.  As I noted in your previous question, please take the time to read [ask] before posting.

Comment: @Jason Will it fit where I want it to?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?  I have no idea how big your image is.

Comment: @Jason Oh, I mean, I can put it where I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding a [stacklayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stacklayout) to the outside of the frame.
Below is the code snippet for your reference:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    
    <StackLayout>
        <Image Source="XamarinLogo.png" ></Image>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="20" WidthRequest="396" HeightRequest="430" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center" >
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Вход на Lockdown" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Title" Margin="0,30,0,10" />
                <Entry  Placeholder="Логин" x:Name="login" Text="{Binding Login}" />
                <Entry Placeholder="Пароль" x:Name ="password" Text="{Binding Password}"  IsPassword="True"/>
                <Label x:Name="LoginMessageLabel" Text="{Binding LoginMessage,Mode=OneWay}" IsVisible="{Binding TurnLoginMessage,Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextColor="Red"></Label>
                <Button x:Name="loginButton" Text="Вход" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" BackgroundColor="#1877F2" Margin="10,10,10,10"
                    Command="{Binding cmdLogin}">

                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="createAccount" Text="Создать новый аккаунт" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" BackgroundColor="#42B72A" Margin="10,10,10,10" Command="{Binding cmdCreateAccount}"/>
                <Label Text="Забыли пароль?" TextColor="#1877F2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding cmdForgotPassword}"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: And how do I insert the picture that I need? That is, where do I need to insert it to get access to it?

Comment: Image files can be added to each application project and referenced from Xamarin.Forms shared code. Since you are using Android emulator, you need place images in the Resources/drawable directory in the Android project.For more details, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#local-images

Comment: The unintended end of the file. The following elements are not closed: ContentPage., line 31, position 23.

Comment: I copied the code you specified above and the bug was found/

Comment: what's problem?

Comment: It is because you need close every control you created, add </ContentPage> to the end of your xaml file.